# multiple selections with datalist

Tags: html, html-datalist

I'm using the  tag to create a list of suggestions for my search box, but I cannot select multiple values from the datalist.  Currently, my HTML is:

```
<html>

  <form action="search_tags.php" method="GET"/>

  Search: <input type="text" multiple="multiple" name="search" list="tags" autocomplete="off" />

  <datalist id="tags">
    <option value="black">
    <option value="gold">
    <option value="grey">
    <option value="pink">
    <option value="turquoise">
    <option value="red">
    <option value="white">
  </datalist>

</html>
```

It will offer suggestions for one item, but after that the suggestions won't suggest an autocomplete for my second option.  I thought that the 'multiple' tag was all I needed (and what is suggested online) but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: According to MDN, multiple only applies to the "email" and "file" types. I think you're out of luck for a traditional text field, and may have to use something like select2.js

Comment: That's unfortunate :(  Is there any sort of javascript package that doesn't use jquery that can do this?

Comment: Most of them depend on a library since there's a decent amount of DOM manipulation involved. There's select2 (jQuery), chosen (jQuery or Prototype), jQuery UI autocomplete (jQuery). I think after that you'll get into less reliable solutions. Why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: Is there any new option to accomplish the same now?

Answer (score 25):

Multiple currently working only with input type="email" and only in Chrome and Opera

Look at this minimalist example:

```css
input{width:500px}
```

```html
<input type="email" list="emails" multiple>
<datalist id="emails">
    <option value="first@example.com">
    <option value="second@example.com">
    <option value="third@example.com">
    <option value="last@example.com">
</datalist>

<br><br><br>

<input type="text" list="texts" multiple>
<datalist id="texts">
    <option value="black">
    <option value="gold">
    <option value="grey">
    <option value="pink">
    <option value="turquoise">
    <option value="red">
    <option value="white">
</datalist>
```

**First input will be working, second NOT.**

You only press comma, and list will appear as same as on click into input.

There's also a polyfill, look at the working example in fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/iiic/gprLnuwy/4/

Comment: Anyone know why just `type="email"` is supported atm? So bizarre!

Comment: @NickGrealy Perhaps because [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-multiple-attribute) shows how this attribute works _only_ in the context of an email (address fields and attachments), and browser vendors are reluctant to step outside what's explicitly given in the standard.

Comment: @bishop - wow, I really hope that's not the reason... because that's pathetic. w3 gave "an example" and everyone deliberately ignored the intention, and implemented the bare minimum (to tick the "supported/compliant" box?). Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that's it, @NickGrealy: in a spec, it's best to implement only and exactly what's specified, regardless of what intent may be obvious. To implement anything implicit is to risk running afoul of future requirements, painting yourself in a corner at worst or undoing work at best.

Answer (score 5):

## Super-simple jQuery tool: [Flexdatalist](https://github.com/sergiodlopes/jquery-flexdatalist)

*I wanted something simpler, but the "multiple" attribute, from what I understand, only works with email and files because the HTML5 devs don't want to open a can of worms, but [devs are considering a change](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/608#issuecomment-251683628). After searching all over, the only way I could get this to work was to **also** get those fancy, useful "#tagHere X" items in the list like on so many websites. It was all or nothing and it solved my same problem.*

Unfortunately, I couldn't find complete instructions on how to use **Flexdatalist**. So, I'm including a super-complete walk-through with a working example, pardon if it it too much...

### 1. Get only *two* files from [Flexdatalist](https://github.com/sergiodlopes/jquery-flexdatalist) on GitHub

- `jquery.flexdatalist.min.js`
- `jquery.flexdatalist.css` (You could do ***.min***.css instead, but you probably want to tweak the CSS)

### 2. Put these two files in the right place:

I used:

```
[DOMAIN]/js/jquery.flexdatalist.min.js

[DOMAIN]/css/jquery.flexdatalist.css
```

### 3. Include the CSS file

either:

- `@import "jquery.flexdatalist.css";` in your `style.css` file already in `[DOMAIN]/css/`

or

- `<link href="css/jquery.flexdatalist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` *between your `<head>` tags of the page with the `datalist`*

### 4. Include these attributes in your `<input>` element that contains your `datalist`

*(along with your other attributes)*

- *`<input`*... **`class="flexdatalist form-control" data-min-length="1" data-searchContain="true" multiple="multiple"`** ...*`>`*

### 5. Include *three* JavaScript statements after your `datalist`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexdatalist.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.flexdatalist-json').flexdatalist({
     searchContain: false,
     valueProperty: 'iso2',
     minLength: 1,
     focusFirstResult: true,
     selectionRequired: true,
});
</script>
```

---

### Working example:

`[DOMAIN]/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flexdatalist Minimalist</title>
<link href="jquery.flexdatalist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" placeholder="Choose a fruit"

  class="flexdatalist form-control"
  data-min-length="1"
  data-searchContain="true"
  multiple="multiple"

list="fruit" name="my-fruit">
<datalist id="fruit">
  <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
  <option value="Cherries">Cherries</option>
  <option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
  <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="Zucchini">Zucchini</option>
</datalist>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexdatalist.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.flexdatalist-json').flexdatalist({
     searchContain: false,
     valueProperty: 'iso2',
     minLength: 1,
     focusFirstResult: true,
     selectionRequired: true,
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

With the *two* files here:

```
[DOMAIN]/js/jquery.flexdatalist.min.js

[DOMAIN]/css/jquery.flexdatalist.css
```

---

An alternative, with great documentation, is: [Awesomeplete](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/)

Comment: This worked for me, but I ran into a problem with searchContain: true. It needed to be search-contain: true in order to work.

Comment: @Peurke not sure how to help. If you find a way, you could add another answer here.

Answer (score 3):

[According to this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) 'multiple' attribute is only valid with *email* and *file* input types.

Answer (score 3):

I found another way around this without using any external tools.

HTML example

```
<input type="email" class="multidatalist" multiple="multiple" name="search" list="tags" autocomplete="off" />
  <datalist id="tags">
    <option value="black">
    <option value="gold">
    <option value="grey">
  </datalist>
```

jQuery code (could also be done in direct javascript)

```
$(".multidatalist").focusin ( function() { $(this).attr("type","email"); });    
$(".multidatalist").focusout( function() { $(this).attr("type","textbox"); });
```

This basically set the input as an "email" type when you have clicked in the box, so the HTML5 multiple datalist works normally.
Then when you click out of it, the input is switched back to "textbox", so that you can submit the form without the email limitations.

This worked for me and saved me having to use more complex jquery/jscript addons.

Comment: Set the title to "Add colors separated by commas" and then the validation error for email won't confuse when entering items.

Answer (score 2):

Customized datalist to accept multiple values:

After each entry press **,(Comma)** and then **Spacebar**

```js
var datalist = jQuery('datalist');
var options = jQuery('datalist option');
var optionsarray = jQuery.map(options ,function(option) {
        return option.value;
});
var input = jQuery('input[list]');
var inputcommas = (input.val().match(/,/g)||[]).length;
var separator = ',';
        
function filldatalist(prefix) {
    if (input.val().indexOf(separator) > -1 && options.length > 0) {
        datalist.empty();
        for (i=0; i < optionsarray.length; i++ ) {
            if (prefix.indexOf(optionsarray[i]) < 0 ) {
                datalist.append('<option value="'+prefix+optionsarray[i]+'">');
            }
        }
    }
}
input.bind("change paste keyup",function() {
    var inputtrim = input.val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
  //console.log(inputtrim);
    var currentcommas = (input.val().match(/,/g)||[]).length;
  //console.log(currentcommas);
    if (inputtrim != input.val()) {
        if (inputcommas != currentcommas) {
            var lsIndex = inputtrim.lastIndexOf(separator);
            var str = (lsIndex != -1) ? inputtrim.substr(0, lsIndex)+", " : "";
            filldatalist(str);
            inputcommas = currentcommas;
        }
        input.val(inputtrim);
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
input {
  border: 2px solid #1E824C;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 3px
}
small {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<label for="authors">Type authors from favorite to least favorite</label>
<input type="text" list="names-list" id="authors" value="" size="50" name="authors" placeholder="Type author names">
<small>You can type how many you want.</small>
<datalist id="names-list">
  <option value="Albert Camus">
  <option value="Alexandre Dumas">
  <option value="C. S. Lewis">
  <option value="Charles Dickens">
  <option value="Dante Alighieri">
</datalist>
```

Comment: when I press spacebar after hitting enter, the space is deleted instantly. In which browser it works like you described?

Comment: After each selection press Comma and then Space. The above jsfiddle link works fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread as "press enter and then spacebar". Still, after pressing spacebar I get the dropdown but the spacebar itself gets deleted and because of that once I start typing the name, the dropdown disappears. Though, it works in a way "comma - space - first letter - left - space - right" (in this sequence the space doesn't get deleted). Including in Chrome

Comment: Still, your approach is indeed helpful and thought-provoking