# HTML5 : how to get several select elements for one datalist?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I tried to get one `<datalist>` element listing fruits for two "`<select>` one fruit" elements.

**Given the html:**

```
Select one fruit: <select type="text" name="fruit1" list="fruits"></select>
Select a second fruit: <select type="text" name="fruit2" list="fruits"></select>

<datalist id="fruits">
    <option value="Blackberry">Blackberry</option>
    <option value="Blackcurrant">Blackcurrant</option>
    <option value="Blueberry">Blueberry</option>
    <!-- … -->
</datalist>
```

The inclusion of the second `<select>` [break my code (fiddle demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/c7VcZ/1/). **How to process to get both of them work on a same datalist** (or similar list of values).

---

**Edit:** `<select />` corrected into `<select></select>` (@richard)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple selections with datalist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of faults with your sample:

1. `datalist` goes within `input`, not with `select` ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp))
2. `select` element can't be self-closing:

   - WRONG: `<select id='fruits' />`
   - CORRECT: `<select id='fruits'></select>`

So you can make both selects appear in your fiddle by giving the select elements closing tags, but they will be empty as datalist only works on input elements.

Off topic, but for using bootstrap formatting, the `<label>` element should come before the `<div class="controls">` section.

Comment: Note: in my fiddle, delete one select in the fiddle, and datalist can work with a single select, even if a bit dirty.

Comment: I'd ditch `datalist` entirely for now - browser support isn't universal and is only recent: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

Answer (score -1):

Multiple attribute is working… but only with input type="email" and only in a few browsers (hope that more will come soon) -> [multiple selections with datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist/26379320#26379320)