# How to submit a ManyToMany attribute in Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

### Background

I am creating a very simple book database with Spring Boot (Spring MVC with Thymeleaf). A book can have multiple authors and an author can write several books, so I have created a @ManyToMany reference in the Book class.

`Book.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Author> authors;
...
```

`Author.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors")
    private List<Book> books;
...
```

This works fine when I insert the SQL values by myself.

### Controller

I have a @PostMapping which will receive the edited form.

```
@GetMapping("/books/{bookId}/edit")
public String editBookForm(@PathVariable(value="bookId") long id, Model model){
    Book book = bookRepository.findOne(id);
    List<Author> authors = new LinkedList<>();
    for ( Author author : authorRepository.findAll())
        authors.add(author);

    model.addAttribute("book", book);
    model.addAttribute("authors", authors);
    return "bookedit";
}


@PostMapping("/books/{bookId}/edit")
public String editBookSubmit(@PathVariable(value="bookId") long id, @ModelAttribute Book book){
    bookRepository.save(book);
    return "redirect:/books/" + id;
}
```

And here my form code:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/books/{id}/edit(id=${book.id})}" th:object="${book}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" th:value="${book.id}"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Book title:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" th:field="*{title}" th:value="${book.title}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="author">Authors</label>
        <input list="author"/>

        <datalist id="author">
            <option th:each="author : ${authors}" th:value="${author.name}"></option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

I now have two problems:

1. How do I pass multiple authors? I thought about duplicating `<input list="author"/>` several times with Javascript (the user can click on a button called "Add another author", and then the entire field will be duplicated). But how can I then parse it in the controller? And how would I name the input list then?
2. I can display the names of the authors in the datalist, but then I would return the *name* of the author back to the controller, but not its primary key. If two authors have the same name, how can I differentiate it? Is there some distinction between "visible value" and "actual value" possible? In the future, I would like to add some explanatory line after the authors name if this is the case (e.g. "John Doe (American author, 1900-1980)", "John Doe (British author, 1950-2000)). But this then won't be the *value* of the field.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See [multiple selections with datalist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist).

Comment: Well, my problem is not so much how to handle multiple selects in a datalist, but rather how to submit the form and how to receive this in Spring MVC. Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: You try to solve so many things (HTML, JavaScript, Thymeleaf, Spring MVC, JPA) at once, you need to break the task into smaller subtasks.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. Basically my main problem is how to submit this form. With JSON I would send an authors array, but how do I translate this into classic HTML forms? If I know the answer (or best practice), I think I can solve the other things on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was not so difficult. My main problem was that I did not know that I could write the *displayed* value between the `<option></option>` tags.

The data binding automatically detects the other models when an id is passed for an attribute. So something like `<option value="1">Example book</option>` is automatically correctly bound by Spring.

An array is also possible by using the same `name` of the `<select>` field multiple times.