# HTML5 - Datalist select multi times

Tags: html, datalist

I just found datalist is a great tag for combo-box input
But I get a strange state that when I selected one time, then I want to change the selection. The select list disappeared
You can see in this example

```
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist
```

Can I do something to make it selectable again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple selections with datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist)

Answer (score 0):

The datalist element has an "autocomplete" function on the input field. When the input field is empty, you see the entire list of options in the dropdown. Once you select an option or start typing, the autocomplete takes effect, and you will only see the options that match what's in the input field, which is why it seems like the list of options has disappeared. This is intended to help users find things quickly in a long list of options. If you want to see the entire list of options again, then you must remove the text from the input field.