# datalist not showing data if it already contains previous value

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I created custom autocomplete where I want to use manual input entry and offer options from DB. So I created javascript code which gets data from DB and puts them into datalist. All works fine for first search but then I implemented separator so I can add multiple values into input field (I want there list of emails). When my code calls ajax again for next autocomplete I see in console that data in datalist were refreshed but browser does not show me anymore any data.

this is the code:

```
   <input list="manual_emails" type="text" name="manual_email_entry" id="manual_email_entry" class="form-control" placeholder="zadaj email" />
 <datalist id="manual_emails">
  </datalist>

$('#manual_email_entry').on('input',function(e){

  $entry_term = $('#manual_email_entry').val();

  $search_term = $entry_term.split(/[; ]+/).pop();


  if ($search_term.length > 2) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/find_email/",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {request: $search_term}

          }).done(function (data) {
            //console.log(data.data)
            var $opt_val = ''
            for ( var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
              $opt_val += '<option value="'+data.data[i]+'">'
            }

            $('#manual_emails').html('')
            $('#manual_emails').html($opt_val)
          })
    ; 
  }
});
```

this is ok after first attempt

[image]

but when I want to search again next, it does not show anything but in code I see that my datalist was refreshed.

[image]

Comment: You may want to give a look at [docs](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)

Comment: This is not jquery autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this article I found out that only email input type works and I have to add multiple value
[multiple selections with datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist)

Also only comma works, not semicolon as separator

```
<input list="manual_emails" type="email" name="manual_email_entry" id="manual_email_entry" class="form-control" placeholder="Zadaj email" multiple />
            <datalist id="manual_emails">
             </datalist>

$search_term = $entry_term.split(/[, ]+/).pop();
```