# enumeration of list elements python

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a list of elements on python, which I can get on index.html page as a dropdown list and send one selected value to another page for handling. The question is that how to choose more than just one element of list. I mean just a few elements without `select` or `chosen.js` libraries?

All working code:

`app.py:`

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

values = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def dropdown():
    return render_template('includes/index.html', values=values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`index.html`

```
<form action="/action" method="POST">
  <input list="myvalue" name="myvalue">
  <datalist id="myvalue" list="values">
    {% for val in values %}
        <option value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If you do not mind me asking, why do you not want to use select? As generally that is how it is done with form and multiple inputs

Comment: @AkibRhast, sure. When I use select, my web page is broken. Thats why I need to know how to add values manually by code

Comment: how does it break? Is it a UI issue or page does not render and throws error message? @abby

Comment: @AkibRhast, page can render. It is UI problem. I asked many time here, nobody could help me. Now, I just need to solve it by another way

Comment: looks like I won't be able to help you unfortunately. To my limited knowledge it is easier to fix UI , than to figure out a convoluted way(I am sure there is a way) to do multiple form submission without using select multiple tag

Comment: @AkibRhast do you know flask, python? I can send you link with full code if you want

Comment: I highly reccomend using the select with multiple tag, and then posting here that you are having issues with UI/CSS. Show us where the UI is breaking, where it needs to fixed. What you have tried. Good Luck!

Comment: @AkibRhast. full code is [here](https://repl.it/@StackFlow/ComfortableAcademicMedian#main.py) I have one input and 5 values in it. But when I send them, it looks like that I have just one elements, not 5. What is the problem?

Comment: you will have to be a bit more clearer by what you mean when you say, "when I send them, it looks like that I have just one elements, not 5." Do you mean 1. When you send the list of values from backend to front end, it renders only 1 element instead of 5? 2. When you submit your form value from frontend to backend you are receiving only 1 value?

Comment: @AkibRhast, I can select 5 value, but just one can be send. Other 4 elements for some reason can`t be  sending

Comment: @AkibRhast, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62049038/adding-options-to-a-datalist) question

Comment: I have added an answer please make the appropriate changes and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

sure the 'list' tag should be in the datalist?

```
<form action="/action" method="POST">
     <input list="myvalue" name="myvalue">
     <datalist id="myvalue" **list**="values">
     {% for val in values %}
          <option value="{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
     </datalist>
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Comment: but in your sample you still can select just one element from list and can`t select more.

Comment: Then you need multi select not selection - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist

Comment: with specific option value it works by pressing comma. but when I read my option data from `csv` it doesnt work. What can be the problem? If you need I can send you link to check it all.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you in making the right changes:

## app.py

```
@app.route('/result', methods=['POST'])
def identify():
    if request.method=="POST":
        multiselect = request.form.getlist('mynumbers')
        print(multiselect)
    return render_template('identify.html')
```

## index.html

```
<select multiple class="form-control val" name="mynumbers" id="mynumbers">
  {% for val in values %}
      <option value='{{val}}' style="color: red;">{{val}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
<button type="submit" class="searchButton" name=form>
```

The output of the above code snippet is:

[image]

The input of the above code snippet is:
[image]