# Formatting the values selected from a MultiSelect element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to select values from a Dropdown and the appearance of the selected values should be like  Australia and Italy (With a background color and the cross).

[image]

I Searched around it and found this link very helpful
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/?_ga=2.123991113.235369533.1591121626-1952468325.1591121626#/material/multi-select/data-binding.html

But I want to do it using HTML and CSS (or JavaScript, jQuery) only and no other external library.
My focus is only the background color and the cross button of the selected values.

Comment: So you want tokenized values (the pills with the close button). Do you want those selected from a dropdown, or freeform? And what sort of external libraries do you want to avoid? (JQuery is an external library). I will warn you that tokenization from scratch isn't particularly simple, which is why external libraries exist. Multi select is a good option, but you are excluding that, correct?

Comment: This question is slightly different but might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist