# Choose multiple data from datalist dropdown

Tags: php

I have this datalist, and right now I can only choose a signle variable, and this variable is sent with a `form`, and used in a sql query.
But my users want to be able to pick multiple data from the datalist, but how can this be done?
Can it be done by a checkbox for each option or?

Part of the code:

```php
if ($SearchParameterArray[$i]['URL'] == "TSC") {
  echo "<input style='width: 100%;' list='".$SearchParameterArray[$i]['FieldName']."' type='text' name='".$SearchParameterArray[$i]['FieldName']."'  value='".$SearchParameterArray[$i]['InputArray']."' onchange='this.form.submit()' placeholder = '".$SearchParameterArray[$i]['PlaceHolder']."'  autocomplete='off'><br>";
  echo"           
  <datalist id='".$SearchParameterArray[$i]['FieldName']."'";
  foreach($_SESSION['TSC_names'] as $dataRow2)
  {
    echo"<option value='$dataRow2'>";
  }
  echo"</datalist>";
}
```

[Datalist picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEpUl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Multiple currently working only with input type="email" and only in Chrome and Opera**

Reference: [multiple selections with datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148538/multiple-selections-with-datalist)

Comment: Not like that, it has to be from the same datalist, not multiple